# Firewall status: "Allowed, Restricted" on a port

Tags: windows, port

I'm trying to run something on my localhost through a port (8080) but I am getting a 404. It should be working properly but I'm not sure why.

[image]

In my Resource Monitor, under Network -> Listening Ports, javaw.exe IS running on that port BUT under Firewall Status it says "Allowed, **Restricted**."

[image]

Could this be why it is not letting me access it through this port? How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Did add a specific rule in the firewall to allow 8080? I would go to advanced Windows firewall settings and add that rule and try again.

Comment: @shinjijai I have added a rule, it doesn't change this firewall status nor does it allow me to access localhost:8080

Comment: @shinjijai Actually, this did change the Firewall Status to Allowed, Not Restricted but unfortunately didn't help my main problem :(

Comment: 404 means it's not found.  make sure your path is spelled correctly.  try putting a file in the root of your webserver directory and accessing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RussellUhl points out in his comment, you are getting a 404 [status code](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/40132?hl=en) *from your web server*.  So you are communicating with the web server, it just can't locate the file you're requesting, and so the firewall is not your problem.

You can test this by turning off your Firewall temporarily (via the UI, not by disabling the service) and it should behave the same way.  If it does then you know your firewall isn't blocking you.

So putting the Firewall aside, if the file requested exists, then it's likely a web server and/or file system permission configuration problem.